# SubSonic.Core with Commercial project

Tags: subsonic3

I love SubSonic Active Engine.

Can I use it in Commercial project?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simple answer yes.

Lengthy answer -> [here](http://subsonicproject.com/docs/License)

Comment: Thanks you for Simple Answer.